# Make linewidth of plot to be different according to time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to make a plot with linewidth of 1 when timeframe is 1min and linewidth of 2 for other timeframes.

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
//in_1min_tf is a boolean variable which is true when chart is in 1min timeframe
plot(series=test_plot, title='Mid', linewidth=in_1min_tf?1:2, color=color.white)
```

The error received is `Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'linewidth'='call 'operator ?:' (simple int)'. An argument of 'simple int' type was used but a 'input int' is expected.`

I am using pinescript v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have to use `input int` in the `linewidth` parameter, you can use `series int/float` to the `series` parameter. You use 2 `plot` functions according to the timeframe:

```
plot(series=in_1min_tf ? test_plot : na, title='Mid', linewidth=1, color=color.white)
plot(series=in_1min_tf ? na : test_plot, title='Mid', linewidth=2, color=color.white)
```